# Why does get_template_directory_uri() return differently between pages?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 2 pages, 'projects' and 'events'...both using custom page templates.

In my `footer.php` file I have the following:

```
<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>
```

Simple. However, on 'projects' it outputs as (wrongly):

> http://localhost:8888/future-cities-catapult/wp-content/themes/future-cities

But on 'events' it outputs as (correctly):

> //localhost:8080/future-cities-catapult/wp-content/themes/future-cities

They're similar, but because the port number is different (I am viewing the website with Browser-Sync on `8080`) when I attempt to use this variable in my JavaScript to make an AJAX request, I get an origin request error.

For example, In my `footer.php`, I am storing a global JS variable for use in my scripts like so:

```
<script>
    var website = {
        themePath : '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>' 
    };
</script>
```

So I can access `window.website.themePath` anywhere in my scripts. But because the output is on `8888` and not `8080` with 'projects', I get the AJAX error.

I just can't understand why WordPress is outputting anything differently at all.

Comment: You can try by localizing variable for that particular JS file( I don't know what it will give as output of get_template_directory_uri(). But you can definitely give it a go to check).

Comment: This isn't directly about my JS, it's about why WP would output differently between pages. It makes no sense.